# Grounding wire on plug in lamp, what do I do with it?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have this new lamp that says it’s a convertible pendant lamp that can be used either as hardwired into the ceiling or just plugged into a wall socket. I just want to plug it into the wall socket, so what do I do with this grounding wire?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure the lamp is actually *UL Listed* (or ETL or CSA).  We see a lot of cheap crud sourced from China (which is illegal to sell in retail stores; however a lot is mail-order or sold in fly-by-night informal shops or flea markets). We also see a few home-brew lamp builders who don't care about safety.

I am a bit surprised if UL would approve a separate ground wire like that; but if the UL mark is there on the fixture (not the socket, the fixture)... then OK.

ETL and CSA are valid substitutes for UL.

Beware usually-faked marks like CE, CCC, RoHS or FCC.

If UL approved it, they approved instructions also. Always follow the instructions. (NEC 110.3)

However I would expect the ground lug to be attached to the socket's cover plate screw. (why aren't they using a 3-prong receptacle???)